# .rawQuery multiple ? parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use the .rawQuery to return the contents of a column in an SQLite database.
I have a list that is used to query the database and depending on what is clicked depends on what is returned.  The problem is that the first item in the list wants to return all results and those below it only certain results.

I am using the following code:

```
  public Cursor getTrailByType(String id) {
     String[] args={id};

     return(getReadableDatabase()
          rawQuery("SELECT _id, NAME FROM trail WHERE TYPE_id=? OR ENT=?",
                args));
  }
```

TYPE_id is the specific result to return (if ? is between 2 and 10)  and ENT is return all (if ? = 1 ; I have simply added a second column ENT with the number 1 in all rows). So, if id is 1 it returns the ENT criteria but if it is between 2 and 10 it returns the TYPE_id criteria.

The problem is the second ? is not read and a blank list is produced.  If I substitue the second ? for an integer then it works but does not populate the specific lists properly.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the code?

Comment: You do not need additional ENT column. See example below.

Comment: As said, you don't need a new column for this, but the reason it didn't work is your args array only has one element. Two ?'s -> two arguments. Personally, I would use two different queries to make things more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
public Cursor getTrailByType(String id, boolean needAll) {    
    String[] args = null;
    String query = "SELECT _id, NAME FROM trail";

    if(!needAll){
        query += " WHERE TYPE_id=?";
        args = new String[]{id};
    }
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, args));
}
```

Comment: This does return all the content but for all list entries.  If I click on the second list item I only want those DB entries where TYPE_id is 2. Is it possible?

Comment: my call is as follows getTrailByType(passedVar, false) which returns the following fault  06-14 15:08:52.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(778): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, NAME FROM trail TYPE_id=?

Comment: You missed WERE clause. Check the sample and correct your code

Comment: Thanks woodshy, I had to convert my passed value to an int then add call the boolean needAll true flase using                      String string = passedVar;  
        int passedInt = Integer.parseInt(string); 
        
        if (passedInt==1) { passedVar1 = true;
         
        }             and it worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of ENT column and try this ...

```
// put any id and 1 as ent to get all put id and ent=0 to get specific id
public Cursor getTrailByType(String id, int ent) {
   String[] args={id, Integer.toString(ent)}; 
   return(getReadableDatabase().
              rawQuery("SELECT _id, NAME FROM trail WHERE TYPE_id=? OR 1=?", args));
}
```

EDIT: heh need to convert int to string

Comment: I have tried this and it won't compile as tries to change the int ent to a string

Comment: heh forgot to change int to string hehe String[] args={id, Integer.toString(ent)};

Comment: I also managed toget this solution to work solution (see above comments).  Many thanks, hopefully with a little more practise it will be me helping in future. Thanks again